# Explanation of summation notation when inequality and equality are in the index

Tags: summation, notation, index-notation

I recently came acrossed the following notation:
$\sum_{\substack{
   j\leq j'=1}}^{2^i-1} a_{j,j'}$

Frankly, I don't know how to interpret the index portion correctly. Say that i=2 (as is the case I am trying to work with). The top is then equal to 3. Would that mean we would compute: $a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+a_{2,2}+a_{2,3}+a_{3,3}$?

edit: I came across the notation in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08718) paper, specifically in equation (4).

edit 2: I reached out to some of the authors of the paper, one of which got back to me and explained what was intended by the notation. @ConMan provided an answer that is equivalent to the authors so I have marked their reply as correct.

Comment: Someone presumably derived this formula for a particular set of circumstances from which we might deduce what was intended. My guess is that in your example we should also include $a_{1,3}$ in the sum.

Comment: If you want something better than a guess, you could try including more information about the context in which this formula came up.

Comment: @DavidK I added the paper where I came across the notation

Comment: I think one would need to be more familiar with this specialized topic (or need to follow some of the references) to be sure what the authors had in mind, but Equation (1) shows that $j$ can be $0$, so I wonder if we're not supposed to add $a_{0,1}, a_{0,2},$ and $a_{0,3}.$ The formula apparently comes from the master's thesis of Rafael Díaz Hernández Rojas, so maybe you could track that down, or you could try sending email to the address that appears under the list of authors, next to "Correspondence:".

Comment: @DavidK I appreciate your help a lot, this is definitely some chewy stuff here.

Comment: @DavidK I'm not sure if you care or not, but an author on the explained to me that the reason why j can equal 0, but that index is not included in the sum is that there is a normalization constraint on the frequencies, and so that information is carried through even if we do not include it in the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is a bit fuzzy, since it's combining two different standard notations - on the one hand, you can write $\sum_{j=1}^{2^i-1}$ to mean "sum from $j = 1$ to $j = 2^i-1$", and on the other you can write $\sum_{j \leq j'}$ the mean "sum over values of $j$ (probably natural numbers) such that $j \leq j'$".

I would personally read this as being the sum over all values of $j'$ from $1$ to $2^i - 1$, and all values of $j$ that are less than or equal to $j'$, i.e. it's equivalent to the double sum notation

$$\sum_{j'=1}^{2^i-1} \sum_{j \leq j'} a_{j,j'}$$

and in the case of $i = 2$, that would mean it's equivalent to $a_{1,1} + a_{1,2} + a_{2,2} + a_{1,3} + a_{2,3} + a_{3,3}$.

Comment: So you're thinking $$\sum_{j'=1}^{2^i-1} \sum_{j=1}^{j'} a_{j,j'}.$$ That's my guess too. Also written $$\sum_{1\leq j\leq j'\leq 2^i-1} a_{j,j'}.$$ As opposed to sums that allow some other lower bound of $j,$ such as $$\sum_{j'=1}^{2^i-1} \sum_{j=0}^{j'} a_{j,j'}$$ (which we could probably rule out if we knew what values of $a_{j,j'}$ are defined and what the sum is for).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I edited the post to include a link to the paper where I came across the notation.

Comment: On reading the paper I am led to suspect that the range of $j$ actually should start at $0$ rather than $1,$ but if so, then there are other inconsistencies in the notation.